# htaccess php_value works only if not nested

Tags: .htaccess

I have this htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_env.c>
    SetEnvIf Request_URI ".*/my/path/to/api.php$" IS_MY_PATH
</IfModule>

<IfDefine IS_MY_PATH>
    php_value max_input_vars 5000
</IfDefine>
```

in php `getenv('IS_MY_PATH')` returns 1 but `ini_get('max_input_vars')` returns 1000

I've also tried

```
<IfModule mod_env.c>
    SetEnvIf Request_URI ".*/my/path/to/api.php$" IS_MY_PATH
</IfModule>

<If "%{ENV:IS_MY_PATH} == '1'">
    php_value max_input_vars 5000
</If>
```

but doesn't work either

```
<IfModule mod_env.c>
    SetEnvIf Request_URI ".*/my/path/to/api.php$" IS_MY_PATH
</IfModule>


php_value max_input_vars 5000
```

Only in this case does it work and `ini_get('max_input_vars')` returns 5000 but obviously it's global, not just for `".*/my/path/to/api.php$"`

Any idea why?

Comment: Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? What is the actual URL being requested?

Comment: @MrWhite No other directives, the full url is `website.com/htdocs/custom/my/path/to/api.php`, requested using JS with `fetch(API_URL, {method: "POST", body: formData})`